# How to detect the edition of SharePoint 2010 installed?

Tags: edition

In SharePoint 2007, we have a registry entry HKLM/Microsoft/OfficeServer/12.0/OfficeServerPremium=1 for enterprise edition and OfficeServerPremium=0 for standard edition.

How can I determine which edition of SharePoint 2010 is installed on a machine?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the article [How To: Detect the Installed SKU of SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721969.aspx) on MSDN. It has a list of GUIDs for each SKU:

- **BEED1F75-C398-4447-AEF1-E66E1F0DF91E**: SharePoint Foundation 2010
- **1328E89E-7EC8-4F7E-809E-7E945796E511**: Search Server Express 2010
- **B2C0B444-3914-4ACB-A0B8-7CF50A8F7AA0**: SharePoint Server 2010 Standard Trial
- **3FDFBCC8-B3E4-4482-91FA-122C6432805C**: SharePoint Server 2010 Standard
- **88BED06D-8C6B-4E62-AB01-546D6005FE97**: SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise Trial
- **D5595F62-449B-4061-B0B2-0CBAD410BB51**: SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise
- **BC4C1C97-9013-4033-A0DD-9DC9E6D6C887**: Search Server 2010 Trial
- **08460AA2-A176-442C-BDCA-26928704D80B**: Search Server 2010
- **84902853-59F6-4B20-BC7C-DE4F419FEFAD**: Project Server 2010 Trial
- **ED21638F-97FF-4A65-AD9B-6889B93065E2**: Project Server 2010
- **926E4E17-087B-47D1-8BD7-91A394BC6196**: Office Web Companions 2010

You can look for these within the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\InstalledProducts`.

You can also use the PowerShell command `get-spfarm | select Products` to output GUIDs for the installed SKUs.

Comment: If you have SharePoint Server 2010 Standard, does the SharePoint Foundation GUID always get returned as well?

Comment: @TempaC SharePoint Foundation is the foundation to SharePoint Server, so yes it is included as an installed product.

Answer (score 8):

You can follow this guide to identify all versions of SharePoint:

http://www.sharepointdesignerstepbystep.com/Blog/Articles/How%20To%20find%20the%20SharePoint%20version.aspx

In 2010, you can also specifically visit the SharePoint 2010 Central Administration Web site, then 'Upgrade and Migration', then 'Check product and patch installation status' to show version numbers and what components are installed on what servers.

Answer (score 3):

[How to detect the edition of SharePoint 2010 installed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/how-to-detect-the-edition-of-sharepoint-2010-installed)

A little bit detailed article on "Get SharePoint version programmatically"  at

[Get SharePoint version programmatically - C# and PowerShell examples](http://tad.co.in/?p=599)

Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not the admin or don't have access to the machine or system registry:

a) Use "help" or "?" link in top navigation bar!

b) or point a browser to `http://sharepoint-server/_vti_pvt/service.cnf`. It will return something like:

```
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|15.0.0.4569
```

Version quick reference (also see [more comprehensive list](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sharepoint/)):

```
v12.x = SP2007/WSS
v14.x = SP2010
v15.x = SP2013
v16.x = SP2016
```

Related topics:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511590/how-to-get-version-of-sharepoint-installed
- https://serverfault.com/questions/212107/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-sharepoint-a-site-is-using-from-the-outside
- http://blog.fpweb.net/what-sharepoint-version-am-i-using/

*Thanks to [@Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25887668/14420) and [@MadMac88](https://serverfault.com/users/90558/madmac88)*

Comment: Funny - I tried this trick on this site: http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/default.aspx  and it wanted me to log in!  Maybe that's just the case with Sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 2):

The following link provides information for accessing the version number from the SharePoint Webpage.
http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/08/get-sharepoint-version-number-of-your-platform-quickly/

Comment: Please add a short description of the resolution and use the link as a reference. Link-only answers become less useful over time as links tend to break.

Answer (score 0):

For a customer project based on SharePoint 2013 we had the same problem. For this case we developed a simple Helper, which can be easily adapted for SharePoint 2010. More Informationen about the helper and how to use it can be found here:

http://msscorner.de/2014/06/11/identify-which-sharepoint-2013-edition-is-in-use/

If you wanna use this Helper for SharePoint 2010, you only have to change the SharePoint 2013 SKUs with the SharePoint 2010 SKUs, which are listed above.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

GO to central Admin -> Upgrade and Migration -> Convert Farm License type.
Over there Sharepoint shows 'Current License' type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I [built based on this blog](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-how-to-get-sharepoint.html).  Basically, the only thing I've improved upon is the option to return either the version or the year.

But you can do this from a web-page without any admin access at all.

```
//Returns 12, 14, 16 respectively, or 0 if no version is found (which means it isn't sharepoint)
//see http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-how-to-get-sharepoint.html
function GetSharepointVersion(asYear){
    if(!thisPageIsSharepoint){ return "";}
    //method one
    //var SPversion = (typeof unsafeWindow._fV4UI == "undefined") ? "12" : "14"; 
    //var SPversion = (typeof _fV4UI == "undefined") ? "12" : "14";
    var SPVersion = "";
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, and so on: Use native object.
    }else{
        if (ActiveXObject) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');  // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6.
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD', unsafeWindow.location.href, false);
    xmlHttp.send();
    SPVersion = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices");

    if(SPVersion == null || SPVersion == undefined){ return ""; }

    if(asYear){
        switch(SPVersion.substring(0,2) ){
            case "16": return "O365"; break; 
            case "15": return "2013"; break; 
            case "14": return "2010"; break; 
            case "13": return "2007"; break; 
            case "11": return "2003"; break; 
            case "10": return "2001"; break; 
            default: return ""; break;
        }
    }else{
        return SPVersion;   //else return the entire version number
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For SharePoint 2016** you can use the [`Get-SP2016Edition`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40031.sharepoint-2016-detect-the-installed-edition-with-powershell.aspx) to get the sharePoint Edition based on the SharePoint SKU.

- **5DB351B8-C548-4C3C-BFD1-82308C9A519B**,  SharePoint 2016 Trail.
- **4F593424-7178-467A-B612-D02D85C56940**, SharePoint 2016 Standard.
- **716578D2-2029-4FF2-8053-637391A7E683**,  SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.

**Additionally,** You can download

- [PowerShell Script to Detect the Installed SharePoint Edition / Version for SharePoint 2010/2013/2016](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-43d93449)
- [Detect SharePoint 2016 Edition Solution](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Detect-SharePoint-2016-3a310bf4)

Check Also, [DETECT THE SHAREPOINT 2016 EDITION AND THE FARM BUILD NUMBER.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/16/detect-the-installed-sku-sharepoint-2016/)