# How can I tell what version of SharePoint 2010 is installed/

Tags: 2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect the edition of SharePoint 2010 installed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/how-to-detect-the-edition-of-sharepoint-2010-installed)

Hi,

I am new to SharePoint 2010, this is my first time using it but I need to know if we are using the free 'Foundation', or the regular (equiv. of MOSS 2007), or if we have some enterprise version or other version?

I do have admin rights on box and can view central admin.  But still don't know how to tell!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has been previously asked and answered:

[How to detect the edition of SharePoint 2010 installed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/how-to-detect-the-edition-of-sharepoint-2010-installed)

Comment: for those of us wanting to know the actual Version of SharePoint, go here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/how-to-determine-service-pack-version-installed-in-sp2010