# How to determine service pack version installed in SP2010

Tags: administration, service-pack

The title is kind of self-explaining as I am trying to figure out which service pack version that is installed on my SharePoint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [this article](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Admin/Pages/SharePoint%202010%20Versions.aspx) on nothingbutsharepoint.com on how to find the versions in SP2010.  And [Todd Klindt](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=224) has a nice break down too.

Taken from Todd's article,

> To see which build your farm is, go to Central Administration > System
>   Settings > Manage servers in your farm (/_admin/FarmServers.aspx)
>
> Or using Windows PowerShell: (get-spfarm).buildversion
>
> To see which build your products are, go to Central Administration >
>   Upgrade and Migration > Check Product and patch installation status.
>   (/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx)
>
> To see which build your databases are, go to Central Administration >
>   Upgrade and Migration > Review database status
>   (/_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx)